# $6^{2x-3}=9x$, find the value of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Given that $$6^{2x-3}=9x$$
>   Find the values of $x$.

My attempt

$$(2x-3)\ln 6=\ln(9x)$$

$$2x\ln6-3\ln6=\ln(9x)$$

I'm stuck here. How to proceed for it?

Comment: you will Need a numerical method,e.g Newton-Raphson

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Lambert W function also works.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Can you show how to use Lambert W function?

Comment: yes i know $$x\approx 2.35179$$ or $$x\approx 0.000515354$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you show it out how to solve by Newton-Raphson?

Comment: see here https://www.shodor.org/UNChem/math/newton/

Comment: $$6^{2x-3}=9x\implies-\frac{\ln(6)}{972}=-2\ln(6)xe^{-2\ln(6)x}\implies x=\frac1{-2\ln(6)}W\left(-\frac{\ln(6)}{972}\right)$$

Comment: Note that the equations $6^{2(x-3)} = 9x$ has a much nicer solution, $x = 4$.  If this is really a precalculus question, then it may have a typo.

Comment: Maybe the equation was $6^{2x-3}=9^x$ that is $2^{2 x-3} 3^{2 x-3}=3^{2 x} \to \frac{2^{2 x-3}}{3^3}=1\to 2^{2 x}=3^3 2^3 \to 2^{2 x}=6^3 \to x=\frac{3 \log _2(6)}{2}$ in natural logs $x=\frac{3 \log (6)}{2 \log (2)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reduces to 
$$\frac {36^x}x=1944$$
after which you will have to resort to numerical methods.

Not a neat problem to solve.